# How to prove this mathematical logic?

Tags: logic

I want to prove this

$$(\varphi\to\psi)\to((\varphi\to\lnot\psi)\to\lnot\varphi)$$

but don`t know how to deal with

because $(\varphi\to\psi)$ and $(\varphi\to\lnot\psi)$ makes question fuzzy

Comment: We'd need more context to be able to answer this.  For instance, what method are you expecting to use to prove the tautology - e.g. truth tables, or a formal proof system such as a Hilbert-type system or natural deduction?  And if using a formal proof system, exactly what rules are allowed?  (For example, in some formal proof systems, what you gave would actually be an axiom.)

Comment: Did you not *just* post this question?

Comment: @SincerelyPrime If you're referring to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2825594/tautology-question), that's a different problem.

Answer (score 2):

Negation Introduction is the (ND) rule of inference that if assuming something derives a contradiction, then you can deduce that thing is false.   Basically defining negation as "if true it would imply a contradiction". $$\neg p\equiv p\to\bot$$

So, *if you accept* that rule of inference, then similar to your [other question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2825594/tautology-question), the proof for the tautology is straightly:

$$\dfrac{\dfrac{\dfrac{[\phi\to\psi]^1\quad[\phi\to\neg\psi]^2}{\neg\phi}{\small \neg\mathsf I}}{(\phi\to\neg\psi)\to\neg\phi}{\small\sf\to I^2}}{(\phi\to\psi)\to((\phi\to\neg\psi)\to\neg\phi)}{\small\sf\to I^1}$$

---

Proof systems vary, so you may also need to write *negation introduction* as a discharge rule, and depending on your proof system's rule definitions this *may* also require first explitly noting the contradiction with a falsum constant ($\bot$), derived through a negation elimination or contradiction introduction rule (*"a rose by any other name, ..."*).

$$\dfrac{\dfrac{\dfrac{\dfrac{\dfrac{[\phi\to\psi]^1\quad[\phi]^3}{\psi}\quad\dfrac{[\phi\to\neg\psi]^2\quad[\phi]^3}{\neg\psi}}{\bot}{\small\sf\neg E}}{\neg\phi}{\small\neg\sf I^3}}{(\phi\to\neg\psi)\to\neg\phi}{\small\sf\to I^2}}{(\phi\to\psi)\to((\phi\to\neg\psi)\to\neg\phi)}{\small\sf\to I^1}$$

Answer (score 1):

The precise details will depend on what proof system you're using; there are many different (sound and complete) proof systems with different rules and operations. However, the first step to figuring out a formal proof (in whatever system) is to understand *intuitively* why the principle is true. Towards that end, let me give a couple hints:

- Suppose I know both $\varphi\rightarrow\psi$ and $\varphi\rightarrow\neg\psi$. Can $\varphi$ possibly be true?
- Consider the statement "$A\rightarrow (B\rightarrow C)$." Do you see why this is equivalent to the statement "$(A\wedge B)\rightarrow C$"? *(Here "$\wedge$" means "and," in case you haven't seen that symbol before. Incidentally, this fact is related to [Currying](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying).)*

Putting these two hints together should convince you that in fact the sentence $$(\varphi\rightarrow\psi)\rightarrow ((\varphi\rightarrow\neg\psi)\rightarrow \neg\varphi)$$ is in fact a tautology (= should  be provable), and will provide a sort of "template" which you can fill in using the details of whatever proof system it is you're working with.

Answer (score 1):

$$\dfrac{\dfrac{\dfrac{\dfrac{\dfrac{\dfrac{[\phi\to\psi]^1\quad[\phi]^3}{\psi}\quad\dfrac{[\phi\to\neg\psi]^2\quad[\phi]^3}{\neg\psi}}{\bot}{\small\sf\neg E}}{\phi\to\bot}{\small\sf\to I^3}}{\neg\phi}{\small\textsf{define }\neg}}{(\phi\to\neg\psi)\to\neg\phi}{\small\sf\to I^2}}{(\phi\to\psi)\to((\phi\to\neg\psi)\to\neg\phi)}{\small\sf\to I^1}$$

[image: is it right?]

I cannot use truth table to prove it for now

Comment: Please learn MathJax.  But yes, if you define $\neg p$ as $p\to \bot$ .

Comment: @hello_mother You may find this useful: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference