# Tautology question

Tags: proof-verification, logic, natural-deduction

I want to prove

(φ→ρ) → ((ψ→ρ) → ((φ∨ψ)→ρ))

I made a proof but don`t know doing right

may you check it whether doing right or wrong?

[image: my answer]

Comment: Why not truth tables?

Comment: want to prove it without truth tables

Answer (score 2):

You should not be introducing a disjunction.   The elimination rule does not need to be belaboured.

- Assume $\varphi\to\rho$, $\psi\to \rho$, and $\varphi \vee\psi$.
- *Eliminate* the disjunction to deduce $\rho$.
- Discharge those three assumptions in turn to deduce $(\varphi\to\rho)\to((\psi\to \rho)\to((\varphi\vee\psi)\to\rho))$

That is all.

$$\dfrac{\dfrac{\dfrac{\dfrac{[\varphi\to \rho]^1\quad[\psi\to\rho]^2\quad [\varphi\vee\psi]^3}{\rho}{\small\vee\mathsf E}}{(\varphi\vee\psi)\to\rho}{\small\to\mathsf I^3}}{(\psi\to \rho)\to((\varphi\vee\psi)\to\rho)}{\small\to\mathsf I^2}}{(\varphi\to\rho)\to((\psi\to \rho)\to((\varphi\vee\psi)\to\rho))}{\small\to\mathsf I^1}$$

Really, all this proof is doing is saying "This can be justified as a tautology by accepting the *disjunctive elimination* and *conditional introduction* rules."

$$\begin{split}\varphi\to\rho, \psi\to \rho, \varphi \vee\psi & \vdash \rho\\\hline &\vdash (\varphi\to\rho)\to((\psi\to \rho)\to((\varphi \vee\psi) \to\rho))\end{split}$$

Comment: Really, all this proof is doing is saying "This can be justified as a tautology by accepting the 'disjunctive elimination rule' and modus ponens ."  No, your proof doesn't say that, because your proof doesn't use modus ponens.  It's the disjunctive elimination rule and conditional introduction.